# no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(QString&)’

Tags: c++, qstring

this is my first time working with QString, I don't know how to solve this error:

Personanetscape.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::basic_ifstream(QString&)’

this is my .h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qmap.h>

typedef QMap<QString, QString> Map;


class PersonaNetscape
{
  private:
    std::ifstream fileIn;
    Map map;

  public:
    PersonaNetscape(QString nameFileIn);
    ~PersonaNetscape();
    bool personIn(); 
    QString search(QString field); 
};
```

this is my .cpp

```
#include "Personanetscape.h"


PersonaNetscape::PersonaNetscape(QString nameFileIn)
                : fileIn(nameFileIn) //this is line 16 in my code
{
  if(!fileIn)
    throw nameFileIn;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Qt and `std` are two separate APIs which are not directly compatible but `QString` provides methods [toUtf8()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8) and [toStdString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) which may help you in your issue.

Comment: Please, try `fileIn(nameFileIn.toStdString().c_str())`.

Comment: Scheff thank you very much, it worked.

Comment: Qt added a lot of stuff which was not available in C++ std libs at the time of writing. Meanwhile, the development of std closed up. So, there is a lot of stuff duplicated (sometimes a little bit different because std is more generic vs. Qt is more application directed). At least, the Qt developers gave their best to add suitable adapters to std classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QFile instead of std::ifstream.

My initial reasoning for preferring QFile over std::ifstream was because in general if I'm writing code that is using QString (or another Qt framework class), and there are other Qt framework classes that achieve what I'm trying to do (in this case QFile), I'm going to prefer that simply because it's going to be easier and I don't have to worry about converting types/weird edge cases.

Scheff added a great reason to prefer QFile when using QStrings that I totally overlooked. He said:

> std::string is actually encoding agnostic where QString provides methods to convert to and from various encodings, and the internal handling of strings in Qt is done with a well-defined encoding. Hence, the usage of QFile will prepare the application for better handling of encoding and locale stuff than "the hack" with .toStdString().c_str().

Comment: For the moment I don't understand all this things, but I will take your advice

Comment: @DavidHume Concerning encoding - FYI: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)